# Prevent "FLUSH TABLES" query from being replicated

Tags: mysql, replication

We have a master-master replication setup for one of our databases. Some automated backup software will issue a "FLUSH TABLES" command before commencing with a backup, but this command gets replicated to the other DB server. When a certain set of conditions occurs that includes a write query to a table, there seems to be a dead-lock condition that results which causes more queries to be unable to either read or write.

To alleviate this situation, is it possible to exclude all "FLUSH TABLES" commands from being replicated to a MySQL slave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something this on the Master in a single DB session to see if this helps:

```
SET sql_log_bin = 0;
FLUSH TABLES;
SET sql_log_bin = 1;
```

This prevents the `FLUSH TABLES;` command from entering into the binary logs on the Master. Therefore, `FLUSH TABLES;` should never see the light of day on the Slave.

Comment: That would be a good idea, but since the replication software automatically issues the command, it's not clear that the context surrounding HOW it sends this "FLUSH TABLES" command is up for modification. I think the best assumption at this point is that we cannot edit the actual SQL query being run.